# Card-body content overflows containing card

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Using a nested Bootstrap card inside another card.  I want the inner-most card to scroll with long content while the cards both maintain full height.  Oddly enough this works as expected in IE11 but fails in Chrome and Edge.  I've tried all variations of h-100 and flex-grow with no success.  All looks good when the inner card-body is empty, but as soon as I add more content than fits on the screen, fail. Also, the scrollbar only shows in Chrome and IE but not in Edge.

Here is the CodePen:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JZqqeV

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.overflowAuto {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="card h-100">
  <div class="card-header">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="patchGroups-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#patchGroups_tab" role="tab" aria-controls="patchGroups_tab" aria-selected="true">Targets</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col-md-2 pl-2">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <div class="card-header bg-secondary text-white">Ungrouped</div>
          <div class="card-body overflowAuto h-100">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li>10.0.10.99</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.99</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10">more stuff here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove overflow:hidden from your body and remove h-100 also from the card div or you can just remove height and overflow property from your html and body

Comment: see the updated codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rKEaNO

Comment: @JismonThomas that just causes the entire page to scroll.  I want the page height to be the same as the screen height, then the inner card body should scroll.  Eventually I need to drag and drop from one card to another without having to scroll up and down the page.

Comment: if you want your height to be same as screen height it is better to use height:100VH for body instead of 100%

Comment: It feels like the card-header and card-body are treated as siblings, so when I set h-100 on the card-body, it's being set to 100% of the card height.  I need it to be what is left after the card-header and card-footer (not shown here) take up their space.  I tried some of the methods used for making a row display with the remaining height but it does not seem to be working with cards.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you're going for? I removed all the `.h-100` classes and changed the `.overflowAuto` class to a calculated height based on the sum of the other heights.

[new codepen](https://codepen.io/mlissne/pen/wXLazM)

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="patchGroups-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#patchGroups_tab" role="tab" aria-controls="patchGroups_tab" aria-selected="true">Targets</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 pl-2">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header bg-secondary text-white">Ungrouped</div>
          <div class="card-body overflowAuto">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li>10.0.10.99</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.1</li>
              <li>10.0.10.2</li>
              <li>10.0.10.99</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10">more stuff here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.overflowAuto {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  // height: calc(100vh - 163px);
}
```

JS

```
var overflowAuto = document.getElementsByClassName('overflowAuto')[0];

//Get the distance from the top and add 20px for the padding
var maxHeight = overflowAuto.getBoundingClientRect().top + 20;

overflowAuto.style.height = "calc(100vh - " + maxHeight + "px)";
```

Comment: It should look like that but that hard coded value in the height calc just won't do. There will be several other elements above this when the page is complete.  Putting in a fixed value won't do as the space above could vary based on several things including browser settings.

Comment: Okay. I threw in some js to calculate the distance from the top so it's not hardcoded.

Comment: Yeah, that works.  Just a shame it feels like a hack for what feels like a bug in Bootstrap.  Now, gotta see what it does in the context of the entire page.

Comment: Yeah, I can't think of a better way. I tried a flexbox approach with flex-direction: column and flex-shrink, and it's not working out very nicely.